# Reading and Writing into CSV file at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to read some input from the csv file and then modify the input and replace it with the new value. For this purpose, I first read the value but then I'm stuck at this point as I want to modify all the values present in the file.
So is it possible to open the file in r mode in one for loop and then immediately in w mode in another loop to enter the modified data?

If there is a simpler way to do this please help me out

Thank you.

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Comment: I personally have expirienced difficulties with writing inside a file. I prefer to read the whole file as a string, then modify the string and finally replace the whole file with the modified string.

Comment: The difficulties might be that you do not simply insert in the place of your reading position, but replace the characters after this reading position. So you have to save the rest of the file write your string and then append the rest at the end of your string.

Comment: Reading and writing the same file is like sawing the branch you are sitting on. You can read and simultaneously write to a second file, then atomically move the second to overwrite the first - which is how these things are usually done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can open the same file in different modes in the same program. Just be sure not to do it at the same time. For example, this is perfectly valid:

```
with open("data.csv") as f:
  # read data into a data structure (list, dictionary, etc.)
  # process lines here if you can do it line by line

# process data here as needed (replacing your values etc.)

# now open the same filename again for writing
# the main thing is that the file has been previously closed
# (after the previous `with` block finishes, python will auto close the file)
with open("data.csv", "w") as f:
  # write to f here
```

As others have pointed out in the comments, reading and writing on the same file handle at the same time is generally a bad idea and won't work as you expect (unless for some very specific use case).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!
I actually wanted to use a pair of nested for loops where one reads the data and the inside for loop writes the data. Can I do this?

Comment: @PoojithChandra no. For this you should write to an internal data structure (a list, dictionary, etc.), and only write to the output file once at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Just like others have mentioned, modifying the same file as both input and output without any backup method is such a terrible idea, especially in a condensed file like most `.csv` files, which is normally more complicated than a single `.Txt` based file, but if you insisted you can do with the following:

```
import csv

file path = 'some.csv'

with open('some.csv', 'rw', newline='') as csvfile:
    read_file = csv.reader(csvfile)
    write_file = csv.writer(csvfile)
```

Note that code above will trigger an error with a message `ValueError: must have exactly one of create/read/write/append mode`.

For safety, I preferred to split it into two different files

```
import csv

in_path = 'some.csv'
out_path = 'Out.csv'

with open(in_path, 'r', newline='') as inputFile, open(out_path, 'w', newline='') as writerFile:
    read_file = csv.reader(inputFile)
    write_file = csv.writer(writerFile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    for row in read_file:
    # your modifying input data code here
    ........
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do `open("data.csv", "rw")`, this allows you to read and write at the same time.

Comment: So will this help me modify the data? Like what I wanted to do is read a particular block of the csv file and the replace it with a new value Any idea about how to do this or if the answer you provided will be helpful for this problem?

Comment: no, you will face error like this here "must have exactly one of create/read/write/append mode"